# connect to sql server through JDBC in powerbuilder 9 with support arabic

Tags: jdbc, unicode, utf-8, arabic, powerbuilder

Given:
1. powerbuilder 9 application
2. microsoft sql server 2008 r2
3. microsoft sql JDBC driver

I have a problem with retrieving Arabic data from sql server 2008 r2 database using JDBC connection (microsoft JDBC driver) in powerbuilder 9.

I'm using the below in powerbuilder 9 to connect to the database but Arabic characters are showing `???????` in the datawindow, i have tried to use **UTF-8** and **CP1256** and still Arabic characters appear `????`

```
SQLCA.DBMS = "JDBC"
SQLCA.AutoCommit = False
SQLCA.LogPass = gs_password
SQLCA.LogId = gs_userid
SQLCA.DBParm = "Driver='com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',URL='jdbc:sqlserver://servername:8080;databaseName=dbname;useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=UTF8'"*
```

The data is saved correctly in the database.

Any idea how can i read Arabic characters using JDBC connection?

Comment: Where exactly do they show up like that?

Comment: 1. Which version of PowerBuilder? 2. Are you certain the database is UTF8?

Comment: Am using Powerbuilder 9, in the datawindow the arabic characters saved in the database are shown ??? ..am sure the problem is in the JDBC connection, because the data is retreived from the database ???
the database Collation: Arabic_CI_AS

Comment: What are you using that shows the Arabic characters correctly?

Comment: Data is saved to the database through an ODBC connection  but in my application i want to read this data through a JDBC connection...
am not sure if the properties i added in SQLCA.DBParm  are in the correct syntax!

Comment: Are you sure that the font you are using in PB can display arabic characters?

Comment: Can you get it to work with ODBC and the same settings the other app is using? That would eliminate everything but the JDBC connection.

Comment: yes am sure that the font in PB can display Arabic, only data retrieved from the Database is messed up.

Comment: I have applied the same settings of the main application but with  JDBC instead of ODBC and still the same.

I have also tried to create a JDBC profile from inside powerbuilder; and a execute a select statment which retreived wrong arabic characters.
this means that the main issue is in the microsoft sql JDBC driver and powerbuilder 9.